# Detachment and non fruitful actions

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, karma

Isnt it slightly confusing bcz everyone in this world struggle hard for his work to get completed for some specific reason like success,money,etc.How it is really possible not think abt outcome. Also it says we must not have attachment if we really attach to something then and only then we can complete plzz some tell me how to follow according to this quoted these are really confusing me.

Comment: Just remember the outcome you want, and do all those that contributes to achieve the outcome but dont expect the outcome will be in favour. Ex: read a lot for exam and write the exam but dont just think that you will definitely pass as you studied. i.e. study to pass but leave the outcome to god and dont get attracted to outcome :)

Answer (score 3):

**There is no 'requirement' to opt for detached or non-fruitful actions.**
If one thinks that, by detached actions, good results are obtained, then that's not detachment. :-)
Detached actions are opted by the people who are disinterested in the worldly matters. If someone has interest in the worldly matters, then it's not feasible to go for non-fruitful actions.

Note that, Bhagavad Gita was said in a private conversation to a person like Arjuna, who had lost interest in the war (duty) and the worldly matters. Hence Krishna explained him the route to liberation/Moksha, which is attained by detachment. But then, liberation is not for all, who have various wishes & goals in their mind.

When one acts *SakAma Karma* (desirous action), then it goes to that system (viz. deity) and one gets the result of it. We may call this as a worship as well. All the worships ultimately are catered by the supreme One only.

> BG 4.11 - The way they approach Me (direct or via deity), exactly in same way I serve them; O Partha human beings follow My path in every way.
>   BG 4.12 - **Acting desirous of result, those who worship the deities** (deva/raksha/preta/pitru) here in this human world, the success happens quickly from those actions
>   BG 9.23 - O son of Kunti, Even those **who being devoted to other deities** and endowed with faith, worship [them], they **also worship Me alone**, following the wrong method.