# Non fruitful actions

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, karma, bhagavata-purana

Isnt it slightly confusing bcz everyone in this world struggle hard for his work to get completed for some specific reason like success,money,etc.How it is really possible not think abt outcome. Also it says we must not have attachment if we really attach to something then and only then we can complete plzz some tell me how to follow according to this quoted these are really confusing me.I want to do something that i love but i dont have that much capital and now i m doing engineering i dnt like it but still i have go do it for family pressure plzz someone suggest me the way to follow my passion or to do engineering according to what bhagwatgita says.

Comment: Attachment causes sorrow, when you're too attached to results you are affected adversely when result doesn't come in your favour, btw Lord Krishna said about work without attachment as a path for moksha, although it may also have significance as general teaching but its a religious teaching for those who seek liberation. You can do rajsic work, attached work for success.

Comment: You have already asked this before: [Detachment and non fruitful actions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/26371/1049). Avoid repeating it and make the original post more useful by edits.

Comment: This teaching is for those seeking moksha which can only be done by renouncing karma and forfeiting the fruits of karma. Not to despair, the way to not be attached to karma and yet acquit oneself nobly in day to day life is by not losing sight of dharma.