# How does one create dispassion for the world according to the scriptures?

Tags: desire

How does one create detachment from worldy goals?

Comment: Looks like it's a duplicate of this question: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/26371/647 Please use "search" feature before posting any question on this site.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto sorry I didn't see the answer thanks for recommending me it.

Comment: You really want to? Worldly goals start with Morning Ablutions to clean your self up :-)